# Django HttpResponseRedirect not working in custom permission (authentication.py)

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I have created a custom permission which checks a user is logged in. I check it through a token, if token does not exists, it is not logged in and therefore it should be redirected to the homepage. I have imported all the necessary requirements like HttpResponseRedirect and other things. This is used as permission_class in my viewset (where in some methods I render response as html template and somewhere as json). Here goes the code:

```
class AccountPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = "Not a valid customer"

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not token:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return True
```

The problem is the Viewset considers the HttpResponseRedirect html from custom permission as True and allows the user to use methods in the Viewset. How can this be avoided?

Comment: According to [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions), the `has_permission` method should return `True` or `False`. It's not possible to return a redirect response.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair. Can you please tell an alternative for this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with rest framework, so I don't know where you could handle the permission denied exception and return the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I found the solution. It would be helpful if anyone needs this in future. I created an exception handler for rest framework exceptions and initiated in settings.py file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'app_name.exception.function_name'
}
```

I created my exception handler function custom_exception_handler in exception.py :

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    # Now add the HTTP status code to the response.
    if response is not None and response.status_code == 403:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
else:
    return response
```

Comment: it would be ajax request and you are returning HttpResponseRedirect, I don't think ajax handles redirect response well. how did you handle that?

Comment: @eugene in my case it wasn't an ajax call. I was simply checking from cookie in request META object. If you are handling this with ajax call, then it is quite simple: you don't need above handler, just check for 403 response in ajax this way "statusCode: {403: function() { window.location='/'}"